Count arrangements with pairs of attacking kings
I have a $1\times n$ chessboard and $2$ pairs of kings in it. Both components of each pair of kings must be adjacent in the chessboard, that is, they must be attacking.
Now, I want to calculate the number of ways to place both pairs of kings in the $1\times n$ chessboard so that none of the pair´s kings attack the other pair kings, for example:
1100000011 This chessboard state has both pairs of kings at the edges, so they don´t attack the other pair kings. Also, note that kings are indistinguishable.
0011110000 However, this case should not be counted, since the 4 kings are adjacent.

The way you have written this is very confusing. You seem to represent your configurations by binary strings, with $1$'s being the positions of the kings, but since there are two pairs of kings, don't we need to distinguish those two pairs? That is, shouldn't a configuration look something like AB00BA with the A's and the B's being the two different pairs?

@sam-hopkins The kings are supposed to be indistinguishable.

Then what does "two pairs" mean? You write that you want "none of the pair's kings attack the other pair kings" but what does that mean if you don't distinguish the four kings into two separate pairs?

@sam-hopkins It actually means that both pairs are not adjacent

I'm sorry, I still don't understand what you intend here. But I guess Noam Elkies does...

The count is ${n-3\choose 2} = C(n-3,2) = (n-3)(n-4)/2$.
Shrink each pair to a single king and remove one of the squares
between the pairs.  Then we're counting pairs out of a set of $n-3$,
so the answer is $C(n-3,2) = (n-3)(n-4)/2$.
For example, the unique $n=5$ setup is 11011;
the three $n=6$ solutions are 110110, 110011, 011011; etc.
And yes, this should really have been on Math Stack Exchange, not MathOverflow.

Alternatively (inclusion-exclusion), after shrinking, pick any square pair and subtract the count of adjacent square pairs: $\binom{n-2}{2}-\binom{n-2-1}{1}=\binom{n-3}{2}$.

Alternatively, if you classify the arrangements according to the number of unoccupied squares between the two pairs of kings, you get the arithmetic progression $(n-4)+(n-5)+\cdots+2+1=(n-4)(n-3)/2$.
